# Windows Firewall Connection Security, require encryption with IPv6?

Tags: firewall, windows-server-2012-r2, ipv6, ipsec, windows-firewall

I've set up Windows Firewall on a Server 2012 R2 to always require IPSec Encryption for all Connection Security Rules.

I've then specified Inbound Rules for specific ports and services, and configured them with the action "Require the connections to be encrypted".

All these settings are done through Group Policy.

This works just fine for IPv4 connections, but not for IPv6 connections. I've tried both ICMP6 and TCP/UDP ports with the same result. Sometimes I can see blocks in the firewall logs (specifically for TCP ports, but not always for ICMP6).

I begin to wonder if IPSec Encryption is not supported with IPv6 in the Windows Connection Security implementation? I've tried researching this but not found anything to support this, other than old documentation for Windows Server 2003.

I might add that the use case in this case is Windows Clustering, which uses IPv6 for internal clustering communication. This could be disabled, but that's not supported by MS, so I would prefer not to go that way.

I don't really need the intraserver communication to be encrypted, but if I don't require encryption for all connection security rules (in the global firewall setting), single rules requiring encryption doesn't seem to work.

Or is it possible to not require encryption for all rules but only for some rules, for instance all communication on port 445?

I've added a few pictures to clarify the settings I'm using.

Global Firewall Setting:
[image: Connection Security]

Action setting in sample inbound rule:

[image: Allow Encrypted]